# Selenium Webdriver using isDisplayed() not working

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Goal: checking if the element exists on the page, if so, continue with the test, if it doesn't show an error and stop the test.

```
Boolean Display = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".mat - select")).isDisplayed();
```

Error CS1061    'IWebElement' does not contain a definition for 'isDisplayed' and no accessible extension method 'isDisplayed' accepting a first argument of type 'IWebElement' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
Boolean Display = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".mat - select")).Displayed();
```

Error   CS1955  Non-invocable member 'IWebElement.Displayed' cannot be used like a method.

I will be grateful for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# Selenium there is no `isDisplayed()` method. Also `Displayed` is a property, not a method.
So instead of

```cs
Boolean Display = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".mat - select")).isDisplayed();
```

Try using

```cs
Boolean Display = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".mat - select")).Displayed;
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, if i understand it correctly: if item
will be found on the page the test will continue if there is no element on the page will the test be terminated? This also applies to fields or just text elements?

Comment: I would not recommend to use this logic. It's much preferred to use expected conditions to wait for element presence or visibility. You may fail on situation when you catch that web element while it is still not completely rendered, so it will be matching your locator but it will still not be visible.

Comment: You can use your logic only when you are totally sure the element you are checking is already completely loaded and rendered.